# Plotly javascript legend lables

Tags: javascript, plotly

### I want to restrict number of characters in a legend and on hover I want to display the full text of legend.

[image]

I Have the above function to show tooltip on mouseover.
I'm trying to change legend text using

[image]

when I do console.log(element[0].firstChild.innerHTML), it gives me substring of legend but on graph it still shows original value.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @sarath o/ This question looks good, but you should swap out your screenshots for code blocks instead. It makes your code much easier to search & copypaste.